# Scribe support for google service account

Tags: scribe

I would like to know if scribe supports Google service account authorization. I did not find any such reference in scribe examples. The service account provides a private key, which I believe need to be included with the request.

If so how can I do it with scribe.

Thanks
Deb

Answer (score 1):

http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.hk/2012/08/google-oauth-2-with-scribe-on-android.html

This is what you are looking for, because I was stuck in their old OAuth 1.0 example.